# What is the camera technique use in desiigner - Panda vidéo?

Tags: camera, action-cam, technical

What is the name of the technique and how do you rig a camera so that it follows the actor's face from the front, like in the two videos below. I would describe it as a "front tracking follow" shot.

- [desiigner - Panda](https://youtu.be/E5ONTXHS2mM?t=23s) (from 00:23)
- [JME - 96 Fuckries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrOwSEpYLKg) (from beginning)

Cheers

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which videos? [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5ONTXHS2mM) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrOwSEpYLKg)? Which techniques do you mean? Color techniques? Camera techniques?

Comment: @user1118321 Yes the Camera Technique... How do they achieve this Frontend Camera Follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It made with [body camera rig](https://www.google.lv/search?q=body%20camera%20rig&oq=body%20camera%20rig&aqs=chrome..69i57.343j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). 
[image: body camera rig]
Here is [tutorial](https://youtu.be/hOdu1Zl1lic), hot to do it yourself, but you will need some adjustments to face it from front.

Or if you don't need hands in the shot, you can use your tripod, how shown in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/lo4_sajFUzc) (careful, bad audio)

Comment: Thank you! But the first tutorial is not really for DSLR purposes isnt?

Comment: It depends on weight of your DSLR, and on shooting conditions... My DSLR Lumix G6 will probably hold well in this rig. But you can make more rigid rig with same materials, if you know, what you doing.

Comment: It is DIY. You always can buy some professional gear, if you desire https://www.google.com/search?q=body%20camera%20rig&oq=body%20camera%20rig&aqs=chrome..69i57.343j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=body+camera+rig&tbm=shop